# Issue importing relatively simple .txt file in SQL?

Tags: sql, insert, sybase, bulk

I can't get either of the following two files to upload into Advanced Query Tool. Here's a snapshot of my data:

```
2,"TEST2",2012-01-01,"TEST","TEST",21111
3,"TEST3",2013-01-01,"TEST","TEST",13111
4,"TEST4",2014-01-01,"TEST","TEST",11411
5,"TEST5",2015-01-01,"TEST","TEST",11151
...
```

I want to import this file in SQL.

Here's the code I've used so far:

```
CREATE TABLE #tb_test
(
id integer,
name varchar(10),
dob date,
city char(20),
state char(20),
zip integer
);

insert into #tb_test
values
(1,'TEST','2015-01-01','TEST','TEST',11111);

BULK INSERT #tb_test 
FROM 'H:\tb_test_data.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',');
```

Alternatively, I could try importing a slightly modified file like the following:

```
2,TEST2,2012-01-01,TEST,TEST,21111
3,TEST3,2013-01-01,TEST,TEST,13111
4,TEST4,2014-01-01,TEST,TEST,11411
5,TEST5,2015-01-01,TEST,TEST,11151
...
```

But, I'd rather not, because the first file was assigned to me, and the second one seems easier (even though I haven't got that one to work, either!). This is the error message I'm getting:

```
Error during Prepare 37000(-131)[Sybase][ODBC Driver][Sybase IQ]Syntax error near 'BULK' on line 1 (0.05 secs)
```

Comment: and your problem is...?

Comment: I can't get either file to upload

Comment: I think what Marc means is "what is the exact error message you are receiving?"

Comment: Here's the error message: "Error during Prepare
 37000(-131)[Sybase][ODBC Driver][Sybase IQ]Syntax error near 'BULK' on line 1 (0.05 secs)." Thanks for the help.

Comment: The header line is not comma delimited. You are telling the bulk insert that every line is separated by commas...

Comment: Those are just the names of the variables - they're not actually in the text file.

Comment: you sure this is SQL Server? Why does your error message have Sybase in it?

Comment: It's Sybase, yes. I accidentally tagged SQL server. Is there a huge different in syntax, though? This is a pretty basic question (that I, admittedly, can't seem to solve, as I'm new to SQL).

Comment: yes, big difference. Hence the "syntax error"

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1510/html/iqapgv1/X100956.htm